# Simultaneous matchedGeometryEffect and rotation3DEffect

Tags: animation, swiftui, rotation

I want to animate a card, which flies from top half of screen to the bottom half and flips during the fly.

I control the flipping logic using custom `.cardify` modifier. It seems working *alone*, e.g. when I flip a card by `onTapGesture { withAnimation { ... } }`.

I also made a card fly from top of screen to the bottom and vice versa using `matchedGeometryEffect`.

**But, when I tap card it flies without rotation.**

I tried to apply `.transition(.assymetric(...))` for both if-branches (see code below) but it did not help.

So, the code

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardOnTop = true
    @State var theCard = Card(isFaceUp: true)

    @Namespace private var animationNameSpace
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if cardOnTop {
                CardView(card: theCard)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: animationNameSpace)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            theCard.toggle()
                            cardOnTop.toggle()  // comment me to test flipping alone
                        }
                    }
                Color.white
            } else {
                Color.white
                CardView(card: theCard)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: 1, in: animationNameSpace)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            theCard.toggle()
                            cardOnTop.toggle()
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }

    struct Card {
        var isFaceUp: Bool
        
        mutating func toggle() {
            isFaceUp.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    struct CardView: View {
        var card: Card

        var body: some View {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .cardify(isFaceUp: card.isFaceUp)
        }
    }
}

/* Cardify ViewModifier */

struct Cardify: ViewModifier, Animatable {
    init(isFaceUp: Bool){
        rotation = isFaceUp ? 0 : 180
    }
    
    var rotation: Double  // in degrees

    var animatableData: Double {
        get { return rotation }
        set { rotation = newValue }
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: DrawingConstants.cornerRadius)
            if rotation < 90 {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: DrawingConstants.lineWidth).foregroundColor(.gray)
            } else {
                shape.fill().foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            
            content
                .opacity(rotation < 90 ? 1 : 0)
        }
        .rotation3DEffect(Angle.degrees(rotation), axis: (0, 1, 0))
    }
    
    private struct DrawingConstants {
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 15
        static let lineWidth: CGFloat = 2
    }
}

extension View {
    func cardify(isFaceUp: Bool) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(Cardify(isFaceUp: isFaceUp))
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**How can I make the card flying with rotation?**

Also, I found that this works (if put in the body of `VStack` alone, no if-branches)

```swift
CardView(card: theCard)
    .offset(x: 0, y: cardOnTop ? 0 : 100)
    .onTapGesture {
        withAnimation {
            theCard.toggle()
            cardOnTop.toggle()  // comment me to test flipping alone
        }
    }
```

but in my app I have a deck of flipped down cards, which are dealt to board flipping up. I tried to model the behavior by if-branch in the code of `ContentView` above (`CardView`s appear and dissapear).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution purely with `.transition` using a custom transition:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var cardOnTop = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
            if cardOnTop {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .transition(.rotate3D(direction: 1).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)))
                Color.clear
            } else {
                Color.clear
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(.green)
                    .transition(.rotate3D(direction: -1).combined(with: .move(edge: .top)))
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                cardOnTop.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

/* Transition Modifier */

extension AnyTransition {
    static func rotate3D(direction: Double) -> AnyTransition {
        AnyTransition.modifier(
            active: Rotate3DModifier(value: 1, direction: direction),
            identity: Rotate3DModifier(value: 0, direction: direction))
    }
}

struct Rotate3DModifier: ViewModifier {
    let value: Double
    let direction: Double
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: 180 * value * direction), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0))
            .opacity(1 - value)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution removes the `matchedGeometryEffect`, so it's less "dynamic" with regards to the two views' positions. It only really works if the offset between the two views can be described with the `.move(edge:)` transition. Is there a way to make this work with two views in separate containers whose positions are just handled by the independent layouts (such as `matchedGeometryEffect`)?

Answer (score 1):

The rotation isn't triggered because you remove the card and insert another one into the view, so only the `.matchedGeometryEffect` remains.

What you want is one card that stays in view so it can rotate, but also change its position.

You can achieve this e.g. with `.offset`. The `GeometryReader` is just to find the right offset value.

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geo in
        VStack {
            CardView(card: theCard)
                .offset(x: 0, y: cardOnTop ? 0 : geo.size.height / 2)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        cardOnTop.toggle() 
                        theCard.toggle()
                    }
                }
            Color.clear
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I want to keep removal and insertion of `CardView`s, is it possible to create a custom transition for that?

Comment: yes, look below :) then you have to take the animation part out of your .cardify.